# Need to write a python script that generates an acronym word from a given sentence

Tags: python

Need to write a python script that generates an acronym word from a given sentence:

- Take multiple strings as input in the form of list.
- Add the first letter of each string to output.
- Iterate over the complete string and add every next letter to space
  to output.
- Change the output to uppercase (required acronym).

You have to generate acronyms for all given strings.  You are free to choose the input and output.

```
def fxn(stng):

    # add first letter
    oupt = stng[0]
    
    # iterate over string
    for i in range(1, len(stng)):
        if stng[i-2] == '':

            # add letter next to space
            oupt += stng[i]
            
    # uppercase oupt
    oupt = oupt.upper()
    return oupt

inpt1 = input("Enter your input1: ")
print(fxn(inpt1))
```

This is not working properly and my peers say that this is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should work:

```py
def fxn(arr):
    oupt = ''
    for stng in arr:
        oupt += stng[0] 
        for i in range(1, len(stng)): 
            if stng[i-1] == ' ': 
                
                oupt += stng[i] 
                
    oupt = oupt.upper() 
    return oupt
```

A slightly more efficient way:

```py
def fxn(arr):
    return ''.join(w[0].upper() for w in " ".join(arr).split())
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite say about the speed (as I have not measured it) but numpy implementations tend to be faster so here is a numpy implementation.

```
import numpy as np

no_of_strings = int(input("No of strings: "))
no_of_char = int(input("No of max. char in string set: "))

arr1 = np.frombuffer(bytes(input("String 1: ").ljust(no_of_char), "utf-8"), dtype='S1')

if(no_of_strings >= 2):
    for i in range(no_of_strings-1):
        arr1 = np.char.add(arr1, np.frombuffer(bytes(input("String {}: ".format(i+2)).ljust(no_of_char), "utf-8"), dtype='S1'))

arr1 = np.char.decode(np.char.upper(np.char.replace(arr1, b" ", b"")), "utf-8")

print(arr1)
```

First we read the input and convert it to bytes numpy array using `frombuffer` after that we continuously convert and add the arrays elementwise in `for` loop. In the end we replace some whitespaces, convert everything to uppercase, and the decode to back to string.
Hope it helps.